Serial killer murders newlyweds and steals their engagement rings
I watched a movie years ago where the basic plot was that a serial killer went around killing recently married couples and would take their engagement rings as a calling card. I believe one scene took place in a limo where the couple were killed.
Also, if I remember correctly the killer was a woman.
Anyone know what movie it is?

Welcome to Movies & TV!(http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) Please add any details you
know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least
the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in
theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more
likely we can help you.

Possibly 1st to Die from 2003. From an online synopsis:

Tracy Pollan stars in this made-for-TV adaptation of James Patterson's novel as Lindsay Boxer, a crack homicide detective assigned to the mystifying case of the Honeymoon Killer. This masterful assassin is terrorizing San Fransisco, brutally murdering newlyweds and removing their rings when he's finished.

The killer turns out to be a woman and one couple is murdered in a limo (in the novel, anyway).

